# Checking if a Dynamic array out of bounds

Tags: c++

How can I check to see if a dynamic array is out of bounds so I dot not get out of bounds error? I am able to do it with a static array, but having trouble with dynamic.
For example:

```
int *array = new int[10];
int i = 11;

// dynamic array out of bounds
int number = array[i];


delete[] array;
```

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/

Comment: It's *your* code. You do it by maintaining knowledge of how large the allocation was, and then *not* allowing code that potentially breaches said-same. What you seem to be asking is how `array[n]` can be controlled to not breach `n` past 9.

Comment: I understand I am learning principles of secure coding, these answers are great and have helped me understand.

Comment: You have to know. Accessing an array out-of-bounds is [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). The compiler will assume you never invoke UB, but it's entirely on *you* to ensure that.

Comment: Btw; stop using C-style arrays. Use`std::array` for statically sized arrays and `std::vector` for dynamic ones. Forget that C-style arrays even exist.

Comment: I did not write this code. I am given this code to look over and find examples of bad secure coding practices. I am entirely aware that outdated C code is used. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know the container size at compile time, use a static container. If you don't know the container size at compile time, there is now way to catch out of bounds errors at compile time but you can catch and handle out of bounds errors at runtime, e.g. with an STL container.

A dynamic array in C++ is `std::vector`. Your code would look like

```
std::vector<int> array(10);
int i = 11;

// dynamic array out of bounds
try {
    int number = array.at(i); // with out of bounds check
} catch (std::out_of_range &ex) {
    // handle out of bounds exception
}
int number2 = array[i]; // faster, but without out of bounds check
```

`operator[]` accesses the element without check and `at` checks if the index is out of bounds.

You should avoid raw `new`/`new[]`/`delete`/`delete[]`.

Answer (score 4):

When you use the `new` operator to create an array, there is no *in-built* way to ask that array how big it is; so, you'll have to keep track of that yourself, by assigning the size to a variable; like this (given you have the requested size in `rSize`):

```cpp
size_t aSize = rSize;
int *array = new int[rSize];
// Later on ...
if (i >= aSize) { /* Error code ... */ }
else { /* do something with/to array[i] */ }
// And, when you're done with "array," you'll need to free its memory...
delete[] array;
```

However, in Modern C++, you can use the [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) container instead, and this *does* know how big it is:

```cpp
std::vector<int> array(rSize);
// Later on ...
if (i >= array.size()) { /* Error code ... */ }
else { /* do something with/to array[i] */ }
```

Furthermore, by using the `std::vector` class, you don't need to 'remember' to free that container's used/assigned memory when you've done with it, as it will delete itself (and clean-up all its resources) when it goes out of scope.

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, if you know your array size at compile time, you can use the [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) container, rather than `std::vector`, which is more efficient for such 'static' arrays. In your case (changing the name of the variable to avoid confusion with the type):

```cpp
std::array<int, 10> myArray;
// ... etc.
```

Most of the 'simple' member functions (like `myArray.size()`) and operators (like `myArray[i]`) can be used in the same way as the `std::vector` analogues.

Comment: For statically sized arrays, `std::array` is usually a better choice than `std::vector`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Indeed - see edit. (I'm just so used to using `vector` as a catch-all replacement for code that uses `new[]`!)